# Force Unload of Appdomain when using IRegisteredObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We have some background processes that run on IIS ASP.NET websites. To prevent these processes from dying when the application recycles, we implemented an instance of IRegisteredObject, where we wait for work on a server to finish before unloading the appdomain (see contrived example below).

Our code is working as expected, however as we do deployments - old appdomains persist until the work we want is completed (which we want) - however, with frequent deployments / lots of work - we run into a situation where resources on our virtual machines are almost exhausted.

Is there an external way to force an unload (regardless of IRegisteredObject existence) / kill older appdomains? or a way that we can communicate with an older appdomain to tell it to terminate within code?

```
internal class ShutdownHelper : IRegisteredObject
{
    public ShutdownHelper() {
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
    }

    void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        if (immediate)
        {
            WaitForAllWorkToComplete(TIMEOUT /* Some arbitrary timeout*/); // This function returns when all processing on the server has completed
            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
        }
        else
        {
            // Similar logic as immediate but run asynchronously and we only unload if the task completes (in a continuation)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate all domains using this piece of code [Enumerating AppDomains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jackg/archive/2007/06/11/enumerating-appdomains.aspx)

Then, you can execute code on the remote AppDomain using [`AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createinstanceandunwrap(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The domain should have the assembly containing this shared type loaded.

```
    CrossAppDomainExecuteStopper stopper = (CrossAppDomainExecuteStopper)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(CrossAppDomainExecuteStopper).Assembly.FullName, typeof(CrossAppDomainExecuteStopper).FullName);
    stopper.StopWork();
```

and `CrossAppDomainExecuteStopper` must inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`

```
public class CrossAppDomainExecuteStopper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void StopWork()
    {
        // force stop the work
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to enumerate the appdomains - i get back two transparent proxy types and one app domain (my current appdomain). How do i actually get information from the transparent proxies? I would like to atleast see their 'FriendlyNames' so I can make sure i stop work on the correct app domain.

Comment: @badazzhindu I remember that no information are displayed in debug mode but you can access FriendlyName at runtime. BTW, I tried GetData/SetData and data can't be shared accross appdomain :-/. If you need to share information, try to access a static type that host these information inside the appdomain.

Comment: This results in a serialization exception. It is unable to retrieve friendly names for older app domains  ```[HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetAppDomains()
  {
   var domains = AppDomainEnumerator.GetAppDomains();
    
   return new ContentResult()
   {
    Content = domains.Select(a => a.FriendlyName).ToDelimitedString()
   };
  }```

Comment: I have not try it yet but if you return `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` inside the `MarshalByRefObject` ?